# iOS Mapview, MKMapView showsZoomControls

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm trying to setup my MapView so that it shows the zoom controls.
Other properties are working but this one seems unknown to the compiler.  This property is listed in the apple docs for [MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsZoomControls) 
Anyone know why it's shown in the docs yet won't compile?

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true;
mapView.showsScale = true;
mapView.zoomEnabled = true;
mapView.showsZoomControls = true;  // Compile error
```

Error says

```
Value of type 'MKMapView' has no member 'showsZoomControls'
```

Comment: Not available on iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property `showsZoomControls` is **not available** in `MKMapView` for [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsZoomControls). It is available on OS X [though](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsZoomControls).

Comment: Docs are sometimes far from being helpful and a lot is left to us developers to figure it out

Comment: @Joelxxx please see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1451958-showszoomcontrols to the right edge: "SDK macOS 10.9+"